# BeautifulSoup - extracting attribute values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If Beautiful Soup gives me an anchor tag like this:

```
<a class="blah blah" id="blah blah" href="link.html"></a>
```

How would I retrieve the value of the `href` attribute?

Answer (score 10):

If you already have the anchor, grab the `href` attribute like this:

```
href = anchor["href"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
link.get('href')
```

in which 'link' is the name of your 'a' tag