# parsing HTML using soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

By this code,

```
soup.find("li", {"id": "result_1"})
```

I was able to get code same as the picture

And I want to get `data-asin="B0097BEG1C"`, only `B0097BEF1C` part

Since it is not text and part of HTML code, I can't extract the elements.

[image]

Comment: Where is the language tag? Is it written in php? Care to take a look how to create a post. Btw, pasting `image` instead of `html elements` is highly discouraged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup - extracting attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684120/beautifulsoup-extracting-attribute-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Fetch the value of any attribute like how you use the key to get the value of a dictionary.

```
item = soup.find("li", {"id": "result_1"}).get("data-asin")
print(item)
```